# Ingress to redirect to path within nginx

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx

I built a nginx Docker image that uses this `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        location /dev {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dev;
            index index.html;
        }

        location /prod {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/prod;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

When this docker container is directly exposed (i.e: not running on a k8s cluster behind an ingress) when I query `host/dev/`, Nginx will serve some static files. If the query is to `host/prod`, it'll serve different static files.

Now, I would like to use a Kubernetes Ingress to redirect to the `/dev` or `/prod` paths of the nginx service depending on the namespace. Here is the ingress I'm using in the `dev` namespace of my Kubernetes cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-issuer
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: dev.fancy_domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            # REDIRECT_TO: /dev
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port:
              number: 8080
```

What I would like to achieve is to redirect requests to `dev.fancy_domain.com` to the nginx service, on the `/dev` path.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect requests to dev.fancy_domain.com to the nginx service on the /dev path, you need to  modify the Ingress manifest to include a specific backend for the /dev path. You need to add this ingress and service in the same namespace then only this will redirect to /dev.

You can achieve this by using  [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#deployment) “**nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target**”  this will Target URL or Path where the traffic must be redirected.

Below is the sample example taken from the official doc.

> ```
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   annotations:
>     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
>     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
>   name: rewrite
>   namespace: default
> spec:
>   ingressClassName: nginx
>   rules:
>   - host: rewrite.bar.com
>     http:
>       paths:
>       - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
>         pathType: Prefix
>         backend:
>           service:
>             name: http-svc
>             port: 
>               number: 80
> ' | kubectl create -f -
> ```

Refer to this [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) doc for more information on redirecting the path.

Comment: This doesn't work, because this not exactly what I'd like to do. I don't want to redirect requests to `dev.fancy.com` to `dev.fancy.com/dev`. That would be easy. I want requests to `dev.fancy.com` to go to a specific backend. Within this backend, I want to hit the `/dev` path.

Comment: @JPFrancoia : As per my understanding  when the User hits dev.fancy_domain.com -> Ingress -> NGINX Backend  then from here It needs to be redirected to dev.fancy_domain.com/dev or /prod based on namespace. Is this correct and you are expecting the process for this?